# Use two imageviews in the framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having two image views here in the framelayout. How can i use the second imageview namely +id/CompositeImageViewTextj with selecting width as fillparent and also use the first imageview 'id/CompositeImageViewj'  at the same time.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"     android:id="@+id/framel">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ChoosePictureButton1j"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/color"
    android:text="CHOOSE PICTURE" >
</Button>
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"android:layout_height="wrap_content"        android:id="@+id/CompositeImageViewj" android:paddingTop="100dip"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"   android:id="@+id/CompositeImageViewTextj"  android:paddingTop="100dip"></ImageView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtextj"
    android:layout_width="172dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:hint="Enter Caption" >
```

```
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/okj"
      android:layout_width="63dp"
      android:layout_height="56dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:layout_marginBottom=" 5dip"
      android:layout_marginLeft=" 175dip"
      android:background="@drawable/tick" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/savej"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="62dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:layout_marginLeft=" 235dip"
      android:text="SAVE" />
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. They are both being used at the same time. Simply one would not be visible... We need clarification. What do you want? What are you getting? This will allow us to help you in a much better manner.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wants both the images at same time and at same place.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/framel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ChoosePictureButton1j"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#d3d3d3"
        android:text="CHOOSE PICTURE" 
        >
    </Button>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/CompositeImageViewj"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/truck"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/CompositeImageViewTextj"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        >
    </ImageView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtextj"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="Enter Caption" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okj"
            android:layout_width="63dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom=" 5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft=" 175dip"
            android:background="@drawable/truck" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/savej"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft=" 235dip"
            android:text="SAVE" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to use a LinearLayout? You're trying to use android:orientation="vertical" - which does of course not exist in a FrameLayout.